# How to handle css modules changes in responsive design using ooccss and smacss

Tags: css, responsive-design, less, oocss, smacss

I am studying CSS best practices and methodologies like OOCSS and SMACSS to use in a medium scope project that uses Twitter Boostrap 3 and LESS. I'm starting to get a grasp of these methods but I have some trouble to find out how to handle responsive design and CSS modules relationship.

For example let say I have a button module with all different kind of buttons used in the project (color, shape, size). How could I make the button change depending of the device. The same button should be large in mobile and a normal in desktop.
Following OOCSS I should have 2 skin classes like btn--default and btn--large. But as the HTML is the same for each device I can't switch this class in the HTML. Also using a media query in the module's CSS that would change the size of the button depending of the device size doesn't seem a good idea as I would be coupling the module with this specific need (and what if I want a normal button in mobile later?).

As an other example, I have product section module that have different possible layouts (vertical / horizontal). What if I want to use the vertical layout in desktop and the horizontal in  mobile. I'm facing exactly the same issue. I can easily create 2 different submodules (product--horiz, product-vert) but I can't change them.

I could use javascript to switch classes but it doesn't feel right and would break the design with JS disabled. You could tell me that maybe the design is not right if an element is changing so much from one device to another but it would be a real limitation to restrain this.

So what are your thoughts about this issue. Is there any generalised practice used to face it?

Comment: Your base button style should be defined in the button module in your 'modules.scss'.  Apply any styles here that will transcend across all buttons.  Then handle the differences in your smacss 'states.scss' file (compiled last).  You should have one 'button' section in your states file in which you handle media queries and unique classes that will alter the appearance of the button.  Hope that helps, I can elaborate more if you need.

Answer (score 0):

To use your example for buttons:

Mobile is also tablet and tablets come in a variety of viewport sizes that are just as large as desktop. Media queries are not detecting features, like touch, so making a media query is only for visual at that viewport size. It's best practice to use large buttons and large click areas for fat fingers for every device unless you do feature detection with js such as .touch .btn- {big styles}. I use a little [script](https://coderwall.com/p/egbgdw) to put `.no-touch` and `.touch` on my html, but I don't bother making larger areas just for .touch. I make them for everything if at all possible.

Comment: I agree with what you're saying and maybe the button example is not the more appropriate but do you think a good design should never change some module element skin depending on the viewport? If not how would you handle that change?

Comment: Viewport and device are different. If you want to have people use your componenents with their fingers, design it for that. If you only have a desktop app, then design it for that. If you have both, design it for fat fingers. Use small viewport first css and have everything stack with no floats, then as the viewport width (and/or) height increases create media queries to add other styling for horizontal situations.

Answer (score 0):

Your base button style should be defined in the button module in your 'modules.scss'.  Apply any styles here that will transcend across all buttons.  Then handle the differences in your smacss 'states.scss' file (compiled last).  You should have one 'button' section in your states file in which you handle media queries and unique classes that will alter the appearance of the button.  Hope that helps, I can elaborate more if you need.